# Robotframework If condition

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

When I run this code it says `${month}` not found and `${month status}` is returning `True`:

```
${month status}=    Run Keyword and Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    xpath=//div[@data-title='Cost for Month']
    Run Keyword If    '${month status}' == 'True'
    ...    ${month}=    Get Text    xpath=//div[@data-title='Cost for Month']    
    ...    Log    Dashboard is displaying ${month} Cost Usage for month Text
    ...    ELSE
    ...    Fail    Cost Dashboard is not displaying Cost Usage for month Text
```

Comment: Please format your code block and add more context to your question

Comment: Why should Get Text work in this situation, are you sure this is the right keyword for your scenario?  More information will help us determine this, show us a snippet of the html.

Answer (score 0):

```
${month status}=    Run Keyword and Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    xpath=//div[@data-title='Cost for Month']
${month}=    Run Keyword If    '${month status}' == 'True'  Get Text    xpath=//div[@data-title='Cost for Month']    
Run Keyword If    '${month status}' == 'True'  Log    Dashboard is displaying ${month} Cost Usage for month Text

Run Keyword If    '${month status}' == 'False'  Fail    Cost Dashboard is not displaying Cost Usage for month Text
```

A bit of a crude solution but we came across this situation as well, and solved it using the fix above.

I think your code was failing because `${month}` was being interpreted as a keyword rather than a variable.